# Difference between output and return value in scipy ndimage filters

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, computer-vision, scipy

I'm beginning a computer vision project and I need to compute the horizontal and vertical Sobel's derivatives. I'm using Python together with Numpy and Scipy, specifically the ndimage.filters module.

I can't understand the difference between the return value and the output parameter.

```
   output_x = np.zeros(image.shape)
   output_y = np.zeros(image.shape)
   filters.sobel(image, 1, output_x)
   filters.sobel(image, 0, output_y)

   return_val_1 = filters.sobel(image, axis=1)
   return_val_2 = filters.sobel(image, axis=0)
```

If I plot the return values images and the outputs images I get different results. Why? Can you please help me? I'm quiet confused.

Comment: so the question is: what does ['_ni_support._get_output'](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L307) do? So judging from the code [here](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/stsci_python_epydoc/ndimage/ndimage._ni_support-pysrc.html) it is a shallow copy of output.

Comment: yes, it looks like they're equal but they're not. I'd like to know what is the missing step.

Comment: Can you be more exact on what the difference is between the return_val and output image? Does `ret_val = filters.sobel(image, axis=1, output=output_x)` work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing in an output array will store the result in that array instead of creating a new one.

This is really handy when you need to operate on something in-place to conserve memory.

When you specify an `output` array, the ndimage functions return `None`.  Other than that, there isn't any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data type.

What the `_ni_support._get_outupt` do is `np.zeros(input.shape, input.dtype.name)`, where the `input.dtype.name` is uint8. 
What you did is `np.zeros(input.shape)`, and the data type by default is float.

I have came across the same problem, and figure it by reviewing the source code.